# Can I create a variable with only one bit in the c programming language?

Tags: c, variables, byte, bit

I am new in C. And I wonder can I create a variable with only one bit in the c programming language? or  a variable with three bits.

For example :

```
variable_type var1=0; /* 1 bit */

printf("%d",sizeof(var1)); /* output= 0.125 */

variable_type var2=5;  /* 3 bit ,binary= 101 */

printf("%d",sizeof(var2)); /* output=0.375 */
```

The "sizeof()" notation above is probably wrong. I did something like this to explain myself.And I assume you know. 1 byte = 8 bits.

Thanks.

Comment: No. The minimum bit-size of an object is `CHAR_BIT` bits (usually `8`, can be more). Of those you can use only `1` bit though. `struct OneBit { unsigned int single: 1; }; struct OneBit x; x.single = 0; x.single++;`

Comment: You can create a bit field, but it is always contained in at least 8 bits, as pmg says.

Comment: 1 byte is *at least* 8 bits wide, but C allows for wider bytes.  There have been real-world systems with 9-bit bytes, for example.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Answer (score 4):

> Can I create a variable with only one bit in the c programming language?

No.

Objects are positive multiples of `CHAR_BIT` bits wide.  `CHAR_BIT` is at least 8 bits.  (Uncommon implementations have `CHAR_BIT > 8`.)

An `struct` object can have *bit fields*.  Below, the member `bt` is 1 bit, yet `struct one_bit` is more bits due to padding in meeting the above requirement.

```
struct one_bit {
  unsigned bt:1;
}
```

---

Note:

`_Bool` acts as if it had only one value bit, but like any other object, `_Bools` cannot be smaller than `CHAR_BIT` bits. [@John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger)

Comment: Also, type `_Bool` acts as if it has only one value bit, but like any other object, `_Bool`s cannot be smaller than `CHAR_BIT` bits.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Note added.